# Set file origin when Importing text files to excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with a VBA code to import TEXT files from a folder to excel workbooks. 
My text file contains non-English encoding/origin and I want to import the file with 1253 Greek windows encoding but can't figure out how to add the `origin:="1253"` (if i'm right) in this code:

```
Sub LoadPipeDelimitedFiles()
'UpdatebyKutoolsforExcel20151214
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.txt")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        xCount = xCount + 1
        Sheets(xCount).Select
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _
          & xStrPath & "\" & xFile, Destination:=Range("A1"))
            .Name = "a" & xCount
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            xFile = Dir
        End With
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files txt", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was in a rush...
Here is the answer:

```
.TextFilePlatform = 1253
```